# powershell date comparision need to delete file

Tags: powershell

i have to make powershell file where i need to compare 2 dates and delete folder which is like more than 10 days of last write item . like today is 30 October i need to delete folder where comparision of dates give 11 12 and 13 days

```
     #ChildItem "\\server\Backup" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays.(-30) }
#$fulllist =Get-ChildItem "\\server\Backup\SharePoint Backup\"| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays.(5) }
$fulllist =Get-ChildItem "\\server\Backup\SharePoint Backup\"
#$fulllist =Get-ChildItem "\\server\Backup\SharePoint Backup\" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays.(-20) }

foreach ($fileitem in $fulllist)
{
    $filename_big = $fileitem.FullName
    #write-host $filename_big  
    $d = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $filename_big -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime
    $d1=(get-date)
    #write-host   $d
   #write-host   $d1
   $ts = New-TimeSpan -Start $d -End $d1
   $ts.Days # Check results\
  write-host $ts
   if($ts -gt 10)
   {
    write-host "inside"
    }
     # Move-Item -Path $filename_big -Destination "\\DBORION\d$\backup"

}
```

iam comparing two dates $d & d1 and days are greater than 10 that folders should get deleted.
but with output iam getting its going inside for all folders whether its 10 days or 5 days ,please find output

```
    0
00:58:29.2923431
inside
0
13:33:32.4388907
inside
0
07:02:28.0900378
inside
0
03:52:35.3425970
inside
0
00:58:29.4017400
inside
13
13.08:49:05.4930775
inside
12
12.08:49:06.3403154
inside
11
11.08:48:31.4681438
inside
10
10.08:48:18.6859604
inside
9
9.08:49:01.2220544
inside
8
8.08:39:56.7230423
inside
7
7.08:48:15.3242000
inside
6
6.08:49:03.6123002
inside
5
5.08:49:08.5439345
inside
4
4.08:49:06.6188386
inside
3
3.08:49:07.2066345
inside
2
2.08:49:06.2290185
inside
1
1.08:45:07.0454477
inside
0
08:47:24.1939025
inside
```

ok so i got this

```
$fulllist = Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Backup\SharePoint Backup\" 

$Days = 12

foreach ($fileitem in $fulllist)
{
    $filename_big = $fileitem.FullName

    $deletedate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)
    $Folderdate = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $filename_big -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime


   if($Folderdate -le $deletedate)
   {

        $filename_big
        Remove-Item -Path  $filename_big -Force -Confirm:$false
   }


}
```

now my only concern is its asking for confirmation of deletion, i dont want  that popup box how to bypass that

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your variable `$ts` is a timespan. A timespan can never be greater then 10, because it is a number. In your if clause you should use:

```
 if($ts.Days -gt 10)
```

And some other maybe needfull advices to spare some byte:

- when you define your $d variable, this can be done much shorter: `$d = $fileitem.lastwritetime` - the $fileitem variable itself has the `lastwritetime` property.
- when assigning a function to a variable, there is no need for round brackets: just use `$d1 = Get-Date`. The brackets are only needed if you want to assign a propery of the function, for example `$d = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek`.
- you could avoid creating the timespan by this: `if($d -gt $d1.addDays(-10))`. This compares your file timestamp `$d` with the current time minus 10 days, meaning the point in time exactly 10 days ago.

And to bypass confirmation when you delete files: use the `-force` parameter.

Comment: I dont really comprehend the fact why [timespan] can't compare after 10 but you are right. A good example to show this: `(New-TimeSpan -Start ((get-date).AddDays(-20)) -End (Get-Date)) -gt 20` equals `$true`. `(New-TimeSpan -Start ((get-date).AddDays(-20)) -End (Get-Date)).Days -gt 20` equals `$false`.

Comment: If you create a time span object, just show it in the console. It is an object with multiple properties, like `days`, `hours`,`totalseconds`. And you cannot compare an integer with an PSObject - so you have to choose the property you want to compare and call it, which is what you do by `$ts.Days` - this is a value of type integer.

Comment: Just answered your second question: add the `-force` parameter.